# How does 'System.Web.Http' Compiles in .NET 7 Blazor server Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor-server-side, .net-7.0, system.web.http

`System.Web.Http` DLL compiles in .NET 7 application. I have Used `RoutePrefixAttribute` class in .NET 7 App and the solution compiled successfully, There is no warnings in the Dependencies section. Couldn't find any proper explanation of how that dll compiles. Help me to understand how it works in .NET 7 App.
So can we use `System.Web` dll in .NET 7?.

[image]

[image]

Reference Link: [Here..](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web?view=net-7.0)